# What font is used in the Android Alert Dialogue?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am in need of the font name that is used in the Android Alert Dialogue !  So i can call the same font in a Web  Application.

Comment: it depends on the fonts set for that particular phone.

Comment: i think that it depends on user setting

Comment: After discovering this useful tool called Google i have tracked it down to Droid Sans :)

Comment: @Xavier on mine is "Cool jazz" tomorow i'll have "Choco cooky" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Droid sans. 
http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Droid+Sans
Avaiable as a web font from google.

Answer (score 1):

[The Droid font family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_%28font%29) is the **default** font family on the android platform.

That's maybe off-topic but for your information Android 4.0 is shipped with a brand new font family (see [this google+ post](https://plus.google.com/108548711253225840745/posts/aiJA1ffp4cf) for further information).